# powershell script to find exact string in files

Tags: powershell

I want search my deployment files that have below text. Any help is greatly appreciated.

"E:\abc.net-Batch\test2"

I have tried this but no luck so far..

```
$Path = "\\servername\Test"
$Text = "E:\abc.net-Batch\test2"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\powershellscripts\test.txt"


# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".txt".
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.bat" |
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |
ForEach-Object {
If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
$PathArray += $_.FullName
$PathArray += $_.FullName
}
}
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press enter to exit"
```

Comment: If you have special charachters in your search pattern you will have to escape them. Maybe like this:  `$Text = [REGEX]::Escape("E:\abc.net-Batch\test2")`

Comment: Select-String accepts non-regex input as well. Then use -SimpleMatch, not -Pattern. -Pattern assumes a regex. So in this case `Select-String -SimpleMatch $text`

Comment: Thank you Gert. I used simplematch and it worked. But the only problem I am seeing is it is printing duplicate records when we use simplematch

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld `-SimpleMatch` is a switch parameter how to interpret the same `-Pattern` property.

Comment: @LotPings I stand corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-String` by default returns the properties `Path:LineNumber:Line`,
so use a `Select-Object` to only use path and append the `-Unique` parameter to exclude duplicates.
You can directly pipe `Get-ChildItem` output to `Select-String` and `Select-Object`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\31\SO_54456644.ps1
$Path = "\\servername\Test"
$Text = [RegEx]::Escape("E:\abc.net-Batch\test2")
$Results = "C:\powershellscripts\test.txt"

$PathArray = Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.bat" -File |
               Select-String -Pattern $Text -SimpleMatch |
                 Select-Object -Property Path -Unique

$PathArray

Read-Host -Prompt "Press enter to exit"
```

You have to choose one of the options **either** escape **or** use `-SimpleMatch`
 not both at the same time as in above script.